# Reconciling exponential function results in C++ (Rcpp) and R

Tags: c++, r, precision, rcpp

I am working on speeding up software from my dissertation by utilizing Rcpp and RcppEigen. I have been very impressed with `Rcpp` and `RcppEigen` as the speed of my software has increased by upwards of 100 times. This is quite exciting to me because my R code had been parallelized using `snow/doSNOW` and the `foreach` package, so the actual speed gain is probably somewhere around 400x. However, the last time I attempeted to run my program in entirety to assess overall speed gains after translating some gradient/hessian calculations into `Cpp`, I see that the new Hessian matrix calculated using my `C++` code differs from the old, much slower version which was calculated strictly in R. I had been very careful to check my results line by line, slowly increasing the complexity of my calculations while assuring the results were identical in `R` and `C++`. I realize now that I was only checking the first 11 or so digits.

The code for optimization has been very robust in `R`, but was dreadfully slow. All of the calculations in `C++` have been checked and were virtually identical to previous versions in `R` (this was checked to 11 digits via specifying options(digits = 11) at the beginning of each session). However, deviations in long vectors or matrices representing particular quantities begin at 15 or so digits past the decimal point in some cells/elements. These differences become problematic when using matrix multiplication and summing over risk sets, as a small difference can lead to a large error (is it an error?) in the overall precision of the final estimate.

After looking back over my code and finding the first point of deviation in results between `R` and `C++`, I observed that this first occurs after taking the exponential of a matrix or vector in my Rcpp code. This led me to work out the examples below, which I hope illustrates the issue I am seeing. Has anyone observed this before, and is there a way to utilize the R exponential function within `C++` or change the routine used within `C++`?

```
## A small example to illustrate issues with Rcppsugar exponentiate function

library(RcppEigen)
library(inline) 

RcppsugarexpC <-
"
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> MapMatd;
MapMatd A(as<MapMatd>(AA));
MatrixXd B = exp(A.array());
return wrap(B);
"

RcppexpC <-
"
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> MapMatd;
MapMatd A(as<MapMatd>(AA));
MatrixXd B = A.array().exp().matrix();
return wrap(B);
"

Rcppsugarexp <- cxxfunction(signature(AA = "NumericMatrix"), RcppsugarexpC,     plugin = "RcppEigen")
Rcppexp <- cxxfunction(signature(AA = "NumericMatrix"), RcppexpC, plugin =   "RcppEigen")

mat <- matrix(seq(-5.25, 10.25, by = 1), ncol = 4, nrow = 4)

RcppsugarC <- Rcppsugarexp(mat)
RcppexpC <- Rcppexp(mat)
exp <- exp(mat)
```

I then tested whether these exponentiated matrices were actually equal beyond the print standard (default is 7) that `R` uses via:

```
exp == RcppexpC   ## inequalities in 3 cells
exp == RcppsugarC ## inequalities in 3 cells
RcppsugarC == RcppexpC ## these are equal!
sprintf("%.22f", exp)
```

Please forgive me if this is a dense question - my computer science skills are not as strong as they should be, but I am eager to learn how to do better. I appreciate any and all help or advice that can be given me. Special thanks to the creators of `Rcpp`, and all of the wonderful moderators/contributors at this site - your previous answers have saved me from posting questions on here well over a hundred times!

Edit:
It turns out that I didn't know what I was doing. I wanted to apply `Rcppsugar` to the MatrixXd or VectorXd, which I was attempting by using the `.array()` method, however calling `exp(A.array())` or `A.exp()` computes what is referred to as the matrix exponential, rather than computing `exp(A_ij)` element by element.  My friend pointed this out to me when he worked out a simple example using `std::exp()` on each element in a nested for loop and found that this result was identical to what was reported in `R`. I thus needed to use the `.unaryExpr` functionality of `eigen`, which meant changing the compiler settings to `-std=c++0x`. I was able to do this by specifying the following in `R:`

```
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS='-std=c++0x'
```

I then made a file called `Rcpptesting.cpp` which is below:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

using Eigen::Map;                   // 'maps' rather than copies 
using Eigen::MatrixXd;                  // variable size matrix, double precision
using Eigen::VectorXd;                  // variable size vector, double precision

// [[Rcpp::export]]
MatrixXd expCorrect(Map<MatrixXd> M) {
  MatrixXd M2 = M.unaryExpr([](double e){return(std::exp(e));});
  return M2;
}
```

After this, I was able to call this function in with `sourceCpp()` in `R` as follows: (note that I used the option `verbose = TRUE` and `rebuild = TRUE` because this seems to give me info regarding what the settings are - I was trying to make sure that `-std=c++0x` was actually being used)

```
sourceCpp("~/testingRcpp.cpp", verbose = TRUE, rebuild = TRUE)
```

Then the following `R` code worked like a charm:

```
mat <- matrix(seq(-5.25, 10.25, by = 1), ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
exp(mat) == expCorrect(mat)
```

Pretty cool!

Comment: This is strange behavior indeed, as we would expect the result to be exactly similar. But don't forget that both R and the `double` type of Armadillo rely on double-point precision, which is about `1e-16`: with differences around the "15 or so digits past the decimal point", you are already flirting with the maximal precision possible with `double`...

Comment: Thank you, Jealie! That is a really good point, I should expect around 16 decimal points in a double, correct? From my reading since your comment, it seems that the rest of the decimals are called "noise". Is that correct? I am going to just have to keep reading, because I don't understand what noise means and why this would happen.

Comment: Please see [R FAQ 7.31](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html) and the references therein for a start on the issues regarding floating point precision.

Comment: Thank you, Dirk! That is definitely very helpful. So my friend Grant Brown gave me some insight here. It turns out that the Matrix Exponential in the Eigen library is what I was calling, and this routine does not exactly match R (or the std::exp()) results. The code in my above edit illustrates this. As a sidenote to you and the other informed, Dirk, I have not yet used ~/.R/Makevars to change the compiler to use -std=c++0x, but I am headed that direction :) I hope I'm even saying that correctly!

Comment: Just to clarify: were you confusing element-wise exponentation (`exp(M)` in R) with matrix exponentiation (`Matrix::expm(M)` in R) ?

Comment: Hi Ben! I actually thought I was able to apply Rcppsugar via using .array() on a MatrixXd or VectorXd object. I still don't know if there is a way to use Rcppsugar on a MatrixXd or VectorXd, similar to how I might do this for a NumericVector. But either way, unaryExpr seems to get the job done.